# Deviation from fit and undersampling of data: can I correlate the two?

Tags: regression, sampling, fitting, small-sample, curve-fitting

I am dealing with data measuring the subjects' response delay after a stimulus is presented on a screen. Most subjects respond within 1 second and the dataset is well fit by a linear equation in this time window (0-1 second). Very few subjects(I'd say about 5%) respond later (between 1 and 3 seconds). At first glance, it appears that these later responses are not well fit by the same equation, but I suspect it's because there are so few data points beyond 1 second that it is unable to replicate what the data looks like sub-1 second. 
Is there a way to test/demonstrate this is the case?

Ideally, I'd like to test whether the 'flattening' of the dataset beyond 1 second can be predicted by / is proportional to how much the data is undersampled.
(disclaimer, the data is not obtained by me, the arrow indicating the responses beyond 1 second is instead mine)
thanks!

[image]

Comment: Would you please post the data, or a link to the data?

Comment: added, thanks for your interest!

Comment: I am unable to perform any statistical analysis on the image you posted. Would you please post the data, or a link to the data?

Comment: Sorry I am travelling and only have the figure. However, can I ask if you have any tips regarding how to tackle this? Maybe a weighted fit? thanks